# Remove transition from image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to remove transitions from [this carousel](https://kriesi.at/themes/enfold/shortcodes/easy-slider/) completely. I'd like there to be no transition and for the image to change instantly (no slide or fade etc).

The carousel applies an inline style to transition between slides. I've tried the following JQuery, but it has no effect:

```
$(".active-slide").removeAttr("style");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any class being called to do the transition?

Comment: Just .active-slide.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the HTML tag with the transition effect has a class `.active-slide`. Then you can simply remove transition for the element by doing the following.

```
// setting property transition to have value none.
$(".active-slide").css('transition','none')
// or you can also set the transition to have 0s
$(".active-slide").css('transition','0s')
// If you don't know for sure which element has the transition effect try this
$(".active-slide *").css('transition','none')
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work, unfortunately. The inline styles are still being applied.

Comment: You can add the ```!important``` after the value in the jquery code above. This has to work if it doesn't make sure you know for sure which html element has the transition effect.

Comment: Didn't work either I'm afraid. I think something more is going on within the JS.

Comment: I've updated the code, try selecting all child elements in case you're confusing which html tag you applied the ```transition``` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) to remove the inline style:

```
$(".active-slide").css("transition","");
```

**By setting the value of a css property to an empty string it will remove the property from that element.**